# Pivot rows in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

How do I pivot in BigQuery?

Suppose my table is like -

```
id   event 
----------
1    type 1    
1    type 2    
2    type 2    
2    type 2    
2    type 2     
3    type 1
```

I want to query something like this -

```
id type1 type2
----------
1   1    1     
2   0    3
3   1    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when event = 'type 1' then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
       sum(case when event = 'type 2' then 1 else 0 end) as type2
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Got it. Worked Thanks

Comment: @GovindaTotla . . . Doing a dynamic pivot in BigQuery requires programming -- I think, although you can get close using arrays.

Comment: Well, I just queried for all the event types and there were only about 10 of them. So I just hard-coded the thing and it worked. Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional `sum()`

```
select id, sum(case when event = 'type 1' then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
           sum(case when event = 'type 2' then 1 else 0 end) as type2
from table t
group by id;
```